# How can I limit a subquery [MySQL] with union table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relationship

I have following tables:

- **product_category** (union table)
  product_category_id (PK AI)
  product_id
  category_id
- **categories**
  category_id (PK AI)
  title
  ...etc
- **products**
  product_id (PK AI)
  title
  order
  etc...

I want get all categories with their associated products by union table (product_category) and limit their products to 5 per category, basically an many-to-many relationship, like netflix categories carousel (drama category have 5 associated movies and terror category have 5 associated movies etc...) I've tried this but join is not working as I expected:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
product_category AS pc
    INNER JOIN
categories AS cat ON cat.category_id = pc.category_id
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    products
LIMIT 1 ORDER BY products.order DESC) AS x ON x.product_id = pc.product_id;
```

So... ¿How can I limit products per category? i'am using MySQL 5.7
I dont want to query multiple times the database to get manually products by category, I want do the job by the cleanest way with only query or two at most. ¿It is posible?

Regards.

Comment: Can you add an `ORDER BY` clause to your current limit subquery so that we know what is the logic for which record to keep?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I've tried "ORDER BY products.product_id" within subQuery but it doesnt seems to work. Also GROUP BY. I want to keep records by product_id. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I made a change. Can you see last edit? Please, could you be more "clear" with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 5.7, you may try something along these lines, using an inner join to restrict to products with the most recent `order` value:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM product_category AS pc
INNER JOIN categories AS cat ON cat.category_id = pc.category_id
INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, MAX(`order`) AS latest_order
    FROM products
    GROUP BY product_id
) p2
    ON p2.product_id = p.product_id AND
       p2.latest_order = p.`order`;
```

The join to the subquery aliased as `p2` above restricts to only product records having the latest `order` value.  Side note: Please *avoid* naming your columns `ORDER`, which is a reserved MySQL keyword.

**Edit:** A solution for top 5 products per order, ordered by most recent first, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id ORDER BY `order` DESC) rn
    FROM product_category AS pc
    INNER JOIN categories AS cat ON cat.category_id = pc.category_id
    INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the last tip, I will not use anymore order as a column name.  If I restrict the product with the most recent order value maybe I could not limit the products by category by 5, for example. What do you think? this could be possible with only one query or maybe this can be done with at most two queries? thanks, any help or suggestion will be apreciated.

Comment: If you want top/bottom 5, then you should really consider upgrading to MySQL 8+ so that you may use `ROW_NUMBER`.  I don't have answer for you on 5.7 for your follow-up.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. I will try to use ROW_NUMBER and upgrade my very old MySQL engine version. I will edit this if I could do this with ROW_NUMBER. Thanks for your help, I really apreciate it.

Comment: @elaineee For a freebee, checkout my updated answer for a row number option.

Comment: You rock! I really apreciate your support, I had to made some changes to adapt it to my proyect but of course I made it based on your answers. Really thanks, I past an entery week doing anything to make it work, you saved my life. **Now it works**,. Really I appreciate your help, thanks a lot. Works code to me: `WITH cte AS (
SELECT
 p.*,
    pc.category_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pc.category_id ORDER BY pc.category_id) AS row_num
FROM product_category AS pc
 INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
) SELECT * FROM cte WHERE row_num <= 3;
`

Comment: @elaineee You really don't have to thank me.  Stack Overflow has promised to send me a free pair of socks, and a T-shirt.  That more than makes up for the thousands of hours of free work I have put in LOL.

Comment: Well, Tim, do you deserve many more than a pieces of T-shirts, but you must keep in mind your help makes people happy and more unstressed, you deserve many many beers or coffee cups!  so cheers!